# li class active automatic

Tags: html, html-lists

class="active" automatic change help me.

```
<li>
    <a href="home.php">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
    <span class="title">Home</span>
    <span class="selected"></span>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>                    
</li>
<li class="active open">
    <a href="general-settings.php">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
    <span class="title">General Settings</span>
    <span class="selected"></span>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>                    
</li>
```

I can

home.php on page

```
<li class="active open">
```

general-settings.php on page

```
<li class="active open">
```

Example

Home Page on

```
<li active="active open">
        <a href="home.php">
        <i class="icon-home"></i>
        <span class="title">Home</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        </a>                    
</li>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: explain your question.

Comment: According to page <li class="active open">

automatic active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with php

```
<?php 
$directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
$components = explode('/', $path);
$first_part = $components[1];
?>
```

html part

```
<li class="<?php if ($first_part=="home.php") {echo "active open"; }?>">
    <a href="home.php">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
    <span class="title">Home</span>
    <span class="selected"></span>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>                    
</li>
<li class="<?php if ($first_part=="general-settings.php") {echo "active open"; }?>">
    <a href="general-settings.php">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
    <span class="title">General Settings</span>
    <span class="selected"></span>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>                    
</li>
```